# web scraper fetches website every couple of seconds

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs, html-parsing

I wrote a simple parser which visits homepage of a website and the internal links found on the homepage. Basically it goes 1 level deep into the website structure starting from the homepage and searches for strings matching regex expression. It alo executes JS. Works for emails, telephone numbers or whatever well formated data. This is the code:

```
pages = set()
def getPage(startUrl):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (user_agent)

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Users/mainuser/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs", desired_capabilities=dcap)
#     print("in get page: "+startUrl)
    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        driver.get(startUrl)
        return BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    except:
        print("returning NOne")
        return None

def traverseHomePage(startUrl):

    if startUrl.endswith("/"):
        startUrl = startUrl[:-1]
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/Users/mainuser/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs")
        driver.get(startUrl)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
#         print(pageUrl+" ")
        pass
    except URLError as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    else:

        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

        text = str(bsObj)
        listRegex = re.findall( r'someregexhere', text)
        print(listRegex+" do something with data")


        for link in bsObj.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^((?!#|javascript|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif).)*$")):
            if 'href' in link.attrs:

                if ("http://" in link.attrs['href'] or "https://" in link.attrs['href']) and startUrl in link.attrs['href']: 
                    print("internal aboslute: "+startUrl+" is in "+link.attrs['href'])
                    #absolute link
                    if 'href' in link.attrs:
                        if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                            #We have encountered a new page
                            newPage = link.attrs['href']
                            oneLevelDeep(newPage)

                elif ("http://" in link.attrs['href'] or "https://" in link.attrs['href'] or "mailto" in link.attrs['href']) and (startUrl not in link.attrs['href']):
                    print("outside link"+link.attrs['href'])
#                     print(link.attrs['href'])
                    continue
                else:
                    print("internal relative: "+link.attrs['href'] )
                    #relative link
                    if 'href' in link.attrs:
                        if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                                    #We have encountered a new page
                                    newPage = link.attrs['href']
                                    pages.add(newPage)

                                    if newPage.startswith("/"):
                                        pass
            #                             print("/"+newPage)
                                    else:
                                        newPage = "/"+newPage
                                    pages.add(newPage)
                                    oneLevelDeep(startUrl+newPage)

def oneLevelDeep(startUrl):
#     print(startUrl)
    if startUrl.endswith("/"):
        startUrl = startUrl[:-1]

    try:
#         print("stUrl: "+startUrl+pageUrl)
        bsObj = getPage(startUrl)
        if bsObj != "None":   
            text = str(bsObj)

            text = str(bsObj)
        listRegex = re.findall( r'someregexhere', text)
        print(listRegex+" do something with data")
#         
    except HTTPError as e:
#         print(e)
#         print(pageUrl+" ")
        pass
    except URLError as e:
#         print(e)
        pass
```

Example of usage: `traverseHomePage("http://homepage.com")`

I ran this scraper for a while, and it is unbelievably slow. I copied my project in Eclipse 8 times, and still only searched 1000 pages in 12 hours What could I do improve its speed? I seriously doubt that google bot indexes just 250 pages per day.

I think the bottle neck is the amount of page requests the bot make per minute. It does one per every couple of seconds. I've read about bots making 50 request per second(and that you shouldn't do that). This is not the case with this one.

What could I do to improve the speed of scraping? I am running code from Eclipse localhost. Will it help if I move to a server? Should I somehow tell server to not send me images, so that I use less bandwidth? Is it possible to make asynchronous  requests? Are multiple scripts running at the same time asynchronous? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are loading the web page as if a browser were to access the page. If you open up homepage.com and go to the developer menu then into network (at least on chrome) you will notice this page takes a long time to load. In my case, it took 7 seconds all together with the last file being a google maps authentication file.

Google can parse things quickly because it has servers upon servers to execute the parsing, and because it only looks at a few files, starting at the root directory it visits every link on that page and every link on each subsequent page after that. There is no need for it to wait for the entire page to load. It only needs the raw html of each site.

Waiting for javascript, and downloading the entire site, css and all (instead of just one html file) is what is slowing your search down. I would use requests to get the bare html and work from there.

Comment: thanks for stopping by. Since I often search for dynamic data, there is no option of excluding JS from parsing. Could you provide some code on how to download just html and js?

Comment: When you say dynamic do you mean generated at run time or is it perhaps predetermined in the javascript file?

Comment: The requests module makes it quite easy to download the html of a web page, at which point you can search it for js files and other links, adding them to the queue as you go.

Comment: I don't know how every page operates so I allowed it to make any ajax calls.   So basically, you are saying..if you want to execute JS, you are out of options? About queue you mention. This is actually asynchronous coding right?? How can I create one? Google bots are actually executing JS, I can see it in my logs. There is lots of visitors with UA: Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Safari/537.36

Comment: If you want to access it like a proper web page, you need to let it load like a proper web page. I assume the libraries you are using can't cache resources either so it's like opening a completely new website every time you make a connection, with all of the waiting that comes along with it.